# How to schedule a task in Shopware 6

Tags: cron, shopware, shopware6

I have created a custom scheduled task. I have registered it as well using the following tutorial:
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-scheduled-task#overview
However, in my database, the status of this task is still "queued" instead of "scheduled". This stops the task from executing. How to fix this? I am currently working on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Status `queued` means that a message to execute that task was dispatched to the message queue. If the status does not change automatically that indicates that now worker executed the messages from the queue.

By default (for dev setups!) there is a `AdminWorker`, which will poll and execute messages from the queue as long as the shopware administration is open in a browser. You can also start a worker manually per CLI:

```sh
bin/console messenger:consume
```

You can find more information how to work with the message queue and how to start workers in the [official docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/infrastructure/message-queue).

Comment: Hello. I have aready tried the command you mentioned here and its running other tasks but not the one I created. I know my task was created correctly because it executed fine atleast 2 times and since then its not being executed.

Comment: I think you might need `bin/console scheduled-task:run` as well if you don't have the admin panel open or the `AdminWorker` is disabled. This would queue new scheduled task-runs.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem.
After I had created and registered my task, it was displayed in the database as "queued" and accordingly not executed.
By manually changing it to "scheduled" it was then executed once and set back to "queued".
Of course unusable for productive use.

My error was the following:
In the services.xml I had passed additional parameters for my handler.
Accordingly my handler had a `__construct()` method.
However, the class inherits from "ScheduledTaskHandler" which in turn also has a constructor and expects the parameter "scheduledTaskRepository".
This repository is used to update the status.

The solution:

1. inject the service `scheduled_task.repository` in the `services.xml` into your custom handler
2. call in the construct method of the handler: `parent::__construct($scheduledTaskRepository);`.

In the end it should like this:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

class myCustomHandler extends ScheduledTaskHandler
{

    public function __construct(
        EntityRepository $scheduledTaskRepository,
        [...]
    ) {
        parent::__construct($scheduledTaskRepository);
        [...]
    }


    public static function getHandledMessages(): iterable
    {
        return [ MyCustomTask::class ];
    }

    public function run(): void
    {
        file_put_contents('test.txt', 'test');
    }
}
```